# Pebble watch charging contacts worn out, options?

Tags: soldering, charging

My pebble is getting harder and harder to charge, every time I need to clean the contacts, press hard and hope it charges, and once it does, hold it still..

I am wondering how I can improve the situation, is it possible to rebuild the contacts in any way? I was thinking I might place a bit of regular solder over the two contacts, but I am seeing a few places say thats a bad idea..

[image: Pebble Charging contacts]

Comment: Your watch has had its time. Please support our consumer economy by throwing it away and buying a new one.

Comment: Might not be the brightest idea, but what about copper conductive tape? You cut two very small circles with the machine used to cut holes in paper sheets, and apply the circles on the pebble contacts.

Comment: Are you sure it's the problem of the watch and not the problem of the charging port? Those pins are pushed in there with a spring, which might get weak over the years and prevent proper contact.

Comment: It's certainly *possible* to fix, though I have no idea *how* you should fix it.

Comment: @Arsenal it is quite hard to get it to work with 2 different cables, and a bit of scraping on the contacts tends to help.. which Is why i believe it is the contacts. Also the dark spots in the centre strike me as part of the issue. Would conductive pens help?

Comment: Clean contacts and carefully put some solder (with use of flux) on it that fills the dent and connect suroundings. Use a small drill to make a little hole to fit the pogo pins.

Comment: Fixing the cable as has been suggested probably has a better chance of succeeding than trying to do anything with the pads on the Pebble.  Basic problem is that the super thin gold plating Pebble used on the pads has worn through or worn off.  This problem is common with price concious consumer products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I acquired and used some [Conductive paste](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32823803372.html) to add a layer on top of the degraded contacts. This seems to be working so far. Will update this answer if it doesnt last.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any chance of an update either way after two months?

Comment: @Sparhawk so far still holding up and seems to make quite reliable contact. And if it wears out I still have a load of paste left to redo, so seems to be a good solution

Comment: Thank you for getting back to us!

Comment: I finally cracked and tried this out. In the past, I would fiddle for ages before the Pebble registered as charging. Now it starts charging immediately when connected! However, oddly enough it seems to be charging much slower than before, e.g. +1% per hour. I'm almost certain I haven't bridged the two contacts. I have no idea what could cause the incredibly slow charging. Even if there were poor conductivity for some reason, I would have thought the small distance would minimise this issue (and it *does* register as charging too).

Answer (score 2):

Id personally try rubbing the contacts with a tiny piece of 1000-2000grit sand paper to get some fresh metal exposed and periodically clean it with a q-tip dipped in rubbing alcohol.

Trying to apply solder is not a good idea because 
A: you don't know what material the pins are made of 
B: Too much heat on that pin will surely melt and distort the plastic case possibly ruining the contact area permanently

Comment: The contacts are gold plated.  Sandpaper will remove the gold, and you'll get corrosion added to the other problems.  Cleaning with alcohol is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

For the extravagant solution where you get to buy a new tool you could try something like [this gold plating kit](https://www.goldplating.com/products/pcb-repair-kit?_pos=1&_sid=e6ca43b60&_ss=r). Sand down the contact as @Square Frustration says, maybe use a dremel being careful of the plastic, to remove the old coating and then use the tool at a low voltage setting to replate the gold.

It doesn't look like you can open the pebble easily without damaging it to disconnect the battery before doing this which would be ideal. I would think that the battery charger will provide some device protection. If it is the version from [this ifixit teardown](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Pebble+Teardown/13319) then it may have a BQ24040,

> 30V Input Rating; with 6.6V or 7.1V Input Overvoltage Protection
>   [(BQ24040 datasheet)](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24040.pdf)

That being said there still may be some risk with the battery connected. Do this at your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the cable, not the watch.  It looks like the contact tips have worn away little pits in the contacts over time, and clearly can't really make good contact anymore.

Regardless, focus on modifying a charging cable and not the watch.  The quickest and dirtiest option would be to use something like an exacto-knife and trim away a little bit of plastic that is preventing the connector from moving further into the little charging 'pit' in the casing of the watch.  If I'm not mistaken, all you need to do is trim a little bit off the top of the semicircular band of plastic between the two prongs: [image]

If the magnets are making full contact, then that bit of plastic is probably not preventing contact.  In this case, I would very quickly place a small dab of solder on the tip of each gold prong on the charging cable.  If you mess up, you've only ruined a cable.  Yes, solder is vastly inferior to gold in terms of oxidation, but I have done something like this many of times and it works for quite some time and just requires you clean it more often.

One of the main reasons gold plating is used so often on connector contacts isn't just due to its oxidation resistance.  It is also used because gold is **soft.**  It deforms easily under contact pressure, making for a relatively larger contact area.

**Solder does this too.**  Solder will creep under mechanical pressure over time.  This lets it act as a decent contact material, though for this same reason, it wears out quickly.  Quickly is a relative term though, this fix would probably last you months, and you can always reapply more solder as needed. Also, use a bit of sand paper to clean off any leftover flux on the surface after you apply the solder.

It isn't an ideal fix, but nothing is going to be ideal.  Connectors have a useful life that they're designed for, and they all wear out eventually.  You can extend this service window by using dirty tricks like this and they'll work in a pinch.  But even this will eventually become untenable.

Watches can only hold back entropy for so long.  We can't stop our watches from one day succumbing to entropy, all we can do is remember how they made us feel.

But solder blobs **on the prongs of the charger, not the watch contacts** will certainly extend the life a bit.  They are so small that you should be able to get a little dab on each tip without overheating the plastic they're molded into.  Just be quick, and going against general solder practices, I recommend pre-applying some solder to the iron dip, and just quickly dab it onto the tip of the prong.  It will heat up enough and the lack of flux will help localize the solder to the tip instead of wicking it down.  Remember, you're not trying to make a NASA grade soldering connection, you're just trying to add a bit of conductive material to the tip of the prong.  Nothing about this will be pretty, but it will work.

Comment: The cable plastic mod is likely to not be useful since I dont think the plastic is holding it back and the magnets do make contact.

Comment: That said solder on the cable is interesting, I might try that. I also purchased some [Conductive paste?](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32823803372.html), and am hoping I can build a small layer on top of the gold contacts with that..